# awk and sort and uniq combination does not count properly

Tags: bash, awk, uniq

This is my `file.log`:

```
{"log":"2023-08-20 10:06:59 [DNSHandler:ProxyResolver] Request: [86.104.44.22:63761] (udp) / 'a1834.dscg2.akamai.NET.' (A)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2023-08-20T10:07:02.868627873Z"}
{"log":"2023-08-20 10:06:59 [DNSHandler:ProxyResolver] Request: [86.104.44.22:62682] (udp) / 'th.bing.com.' (A)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2023-08-20T10:07:02.868688906Z"}
{"log":"2023-08-20 10:06:59 [DNSHandler:ProxyResolver] Request: [86.104.44.22:62248] (udp) / 'th.bing.com.' (HTTPS)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2023-08-20T10:07:02.868705921Z"}
{"log":"2023-08-20 10:06:59 [DNSHandler:ProxyResolver] Request: [86.104.44.22:62719] (udp) / 'a1834.dscg2.akamai.NET.' (HTTPS)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2023-08-20T10:07:02.868721225Z"}
{"log":"2023-08-20 10:06:59 [DNSHandler:ProxyResolver] Reply: [86.104.44.22:62682] (udp) / 'th.bing.com.' (A) / RRs: CNAME,CNAME,CNAME,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2023-08-20T10:07:02.868739879Z"}
{"log":"2023-08-20 10:06:59 [DNSHandler:ProxyResolver] Reply: [86.104.44.22:62836] (udp) / 'www.bing.com.' (HTTPS) / RRs: CNAME,CNAME,CNAME\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2023-08-20T10:07:02.868760977Z"}
{"log":"2023-08-20 10:06:59 [DNSHandler:ProxyResolver] Reply: [86.104.44.22:63761] (udp) / 'a1834.dscg2.akamai.NET.' (A) / RRs: A,A\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2023-08-20T10:07:02.868810466Z"}
{"log":"2023-08-20 10:06:59 [DNSHandler:ProxyResolver] Reply: [86.104.44.22:62719] (udp) / 'a1834.dscg2.akamai.NET.' (HTTPS) / RRs: \n","stream":"stdout","time":"2023-08-20T10:07:02.868831775Z"}
{"log":"2023-08-20 10:06:59 [DNSHandler:ProxyResolver] Reply: [86.104.44.22:62248] (udp) / 'th.bing.com.' (HTTPS) / RRs: CNAME,CNAME,CNAME\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2023-08-20T10:07:02.868896564Z"}
{"log":"2023-08-20 10:07:00 [DNSHandler:ProxyResolver] Request: [86.104.44.22:63587] (udp) / 'hlb.apr-52dd2-0.edgecastdns.NET.' (A)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2023-08-20T10:07:02.868912596Z"}
{"log":"2023-08-20 10:07:00 [DNSHandler:ProxyResolver] Reply: [86.104.44.22:63587] (udp) / 'hlb.apr-52dd2-0.edgecastdns.NET.' (A) / RRs: CNAME,A\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2023-08-20T10:07:02.868926565Z"}
{"log":"2023-08-20 10:07:00 [DNSHandler:ProxyResolver] Request: [86.104.44.22:63487] (udp) / 'www.bing.com.' (HTTPS)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2023-08-20T10:07:02.868940116Z"}
{"log":"2023-08-20 10:07:00 [DNSHandler:ProxyResolver] Reply: [86.104.44.22:63487] (udp) / 'www.bing.com.' (HTTPS) / RRs: CNAME,CNAME\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2023-08-20T10:07:02.868953663Z"}
{"log":"2023-08-20 10:07:00 [DNSHandler:ProxyResolver] Request: [84.241.34.239:53210] (udp) / 'yunqos.gamesafe.qq.com.' (A)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2023-08-20T10:07:02.868967065Z"}
{"log":"2023-08-20 10:07:00 [DNSHandler:ProxyResolver] Request: [86.104.44.22:63412] (udp) / 'th.bing.com.' (HTTPS)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2023-08-20T10:07:02.868980656Z"}
{"log":"2023-08-20 10:07:00 [DNSHandler:ProxyResolver] Reply: [86.104.44.22:63412] (udp) / 'th.bing.com.' (HTTPS) / RRs: CNAME,CNAME,CNAME\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2023-08-20T10:07:02.86899756Z"}
{"log":"2023-08-20 10:07:00 [DNSHandler:ProxyResolver] Request: [86.104.44.22:62452] (udp) / 'onedscolprdwus08.westus.cloudapp.azure.com.' (A)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2023-08-20T10:07:02.869020234Z"}
{"log":"2023-08-20 10:07:00 [DNSHandler:ProxyResolver] Reply: [86.104.44.22:62452] (udp) / 'onedscolprdwus08.westus.cloudapp.azure.com.' (A) / RRs: A\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2023-08-20T10:07:02.86904008Z"}
{"log":"2023-08-20 10:07:00 [DNSHandler:ProxyResolver] Request: [86.104.44.22:64304] (udp) / 'www.bing.com.' (HTTPS)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2023-08-20T10:07:02.869059471Z"}
{"log":"2023-08-20 10:07:00 [DNSHandler:ProxyResolver] Reply: [86.104.44.22:64304] (udp) / 'www.bing.com.' (HTTPS) / RRs: CNAME,CNAME,CNAME\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2023-08-20T10:07:02.86907888Z"}
{"log":"2023-08-20 10:07:00 [DNSHandler:ProxyResolver] Request: [84.241.34.239:49270] (udp) / 'update.eset.com.' (A)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2023-08-20T10:07:02.869098025Z"}
{"log":"2023-08-20 10:07:00 [DNSHandler:ProxyResolver] Reply: [84.241.34.239:49270] (udp) / 'update.eset.com.' (A) / RRs: CNAME,A\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2023-08-20T10:07:02.869118703Z"}
{"log":"2023-08-20 10:07:00 [DNSHandler:ProxyResolver] Reply: [84.241.34.239:53210] (udp) / 'yunqos.gamesafe.qq.com.' (A) / RRs: A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2023-08-20T10:07:02.869133298Z"}
{"log":"2023-08-20 10:07:00 [DNSHandler:ProxyResolver] Request: [94.182.110.194:51644] (udp) / 'raja-bot.utravs.com.' (A)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2023-08-20T10:07:02.869147079Z"}
{"log":"2023-08-20 10:07:00 [DNSHandler:ProxyResolver] Reply: [94.182.110.194:51644] (udp) / 'raja-bot.utravs.com.' (A) / NXDOMAIN\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2023-08-20T10:07:02.869225953Z"}
{"log":"2023-08-20 10:07:00 [DNSHandler:ProxyResolver] Request: [84.241.34.239:56795] (udp) / 'dns.msftncsi.com.' (A)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2023-08-20T10:07:02.869242518Z"}
{"log":"2023-08-20 10:07:00 [DNSHandler:ProxyResolver] Reply: [84.241.34.239:56795] (udp) / 'dns.msftncsi.com.' (A) / RRs: A\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2023-08-20T10:07:02.86925624Z"}
{"log":"2023-08-20 10:07:00 [DNSHandler:ProxyResolver] Request: [86.104.44.22:62881] (udp) / 'wns.notify.trafficmanager.NET.' (A)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2023-08-20T10:07:02.869269544Z"}
{"log":"2023-08-20 10:07:00 [DNSHandler:ProxyResolver] Reply: [86.104.44.22:62881] (udp) / 'wns.notify.trafficmanager.NET.' (A) / RRs: A\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2023-08-20T10:07:02.869283006Z"}
{"log":"2023-08-20 10:07:00 [DNSHandler:ProxyResolver] Request: [84.241.34.239:61310] (udp) / 'upd.es-eset.com.' (A)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2023-08-20T10:07:02.869323226Z"}
```

I'm trying to sort only the domain names and the IP with the following command:

```
awk '/DNSHandler:ProxyResolver\] Request|Reply/ {print $5, $8}' file.log | sort -k2 | uniq -c | sort -r
```

This is the current output:

```
      2 [94.182.110.194:51644] 'raja-bot.utravs.com.'
      2 [86.104.44.22:64304] 'www.bing.com.'
      2 [86.104.44.22:63761] 'a1834.dscg2.akamai.NET.'
      2 [86.104.44.22:63587] 'hlb.apr-52dd2-0.edgecastdns.NET.'
      2 [86.104.44.22:63487] 'www.bing.com.'
      2 [86.104.44.22:63412] 'th.bing.com.'
      2 [86.104.44.22:62881] 'wns.notify.trafficmanager.NET.'
      1 [86.104.44.22:62836] 'www.bing.com.'
      2 [86.104.44.22:62719] 'a1834.dscg2.akamai.NET.'
      2 [86.104.44.22:62682] 'th.bing.com.'
      2 [86.104.44.22:62452] 'onedscolprdwus08.westus.cloudapp.azure.com.'
      2 [86.104.44.22:62248] 'th.bing.com.'
      1 [84.241.34.239:61310] 'upd.es-eset.com.'
      2 [84.241.34.239:56795] 'dns.msftncsi.com.'
      2 [84.241.34.239:53210] 'yunqos.gamesafe.qq.com.'
      2 [84.241.34.239:49270] 'update.eset.com.'
```

As you see, for example `www.bing.com` is repeated 2 times in `Request` and 3 times in Reply, but it seems it's counting the second column (IP:Port);

The expected output:

```
      6 [86.104.44.22:63412] 'th.bing.com.'
      5 [86.104.44.22:64304] 'www.bing.com.'
      4 [86.104.44.22:63761] 'a1834.dscg2.akamai.NET.'
      2 [94.182.110.194:51644] 'raja-bot.utravs.com.'
      2 [86.104.44.22:63587] 'hlb.apr-52dd2-0.edgecastdns.NET.'
      2 [86.104.44.22:62881] 'wns.notify.trafficmanager.NET.'
      2 [86.104.44.22:62452] 'onedscolprdwus08.westus.cloudapp.azure.com.'
      2 [84.241.34.239:56795] 'dns.msftncsi.com.'
      2 [84.241.34.239:53210] 'yunqos.gamesafe.qq.com.'
      2 [84.241.34.239:49270] 'update.eset.com.'
      1 [84.241.34.239:61310] 'upd.es-eset.com.'
```

It seems since the `IP:Port` (specifically the Port) is different in the output, it's counting a different line.

I intend to sort them only based on the second column which is the domain name.

Comment: Aren't you mistakenly thinking that computers can realize that `10.10.10.10:12345` is the same as `10.10.10.10:54321`  ?

Comment: @MyICQ yes, they're the same, but I'm not trying to count the IP counts.

Comment: How should we choose which port address to include in the final counts?  You might want a different output format, which lists them all (or perhaps omits them entirely).

Comment: @TobySpeight the IP and Port doesn't matter here. I'm just trying to count the times each domain repeated. For example, `th.bing.com` repeated 6 times and `www.bing.com` repeated 5 times. In the above log you can see the ports are different which is not important for me.

Comment: Regarding `\]` in your regexp - you don't need to escape `]`, it's already literal unless preceded by a `[` that starts a bracket expression, just like `)` is literal unless preceded by `(`.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the input is JSON, so you might want to employ a JSON processor for parsing and extracting the parts needed. Here's an example (with a [demo](https://jqplay.org/s/sk_Y97mLK9L)) using [jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/):

```bash
jq -sr 'map(.log/" " | [.[4,7]])
  |  group_by(last)  | sort_by(-length)[]
  | [length, last[]] | @tsv
' file.log
```

```
6   [86.104.44.22:63412]    'th.bing.com.'
5   [86.104.44.22:64304]    'www.bing.com.'
4   [86.104.44.22:62719]    'a1834.dscg2.akamai.NET.'
2   [84.241.34.239:56795]   'dns.msftncsi.com.'
2   [86.104.44.22:63587]    'hlb.apr-52dd2-0.edgecastdns.NET.'
2   [86.104.44.22:62452]    'onedscolprdwus08.westus.cloudapp.azure.com.'
2   [94.182.110.194:51644]  'raja-bot.utravs.com.'
2   [84.241.34.239:49270]   'update.eset.com.'
2   [86.104.44.22:62881]    'wns.notify.trafficmanager.NET.'
2   [84.241.34.239:53210]   'yunqos.gamesafe.qq.com.'
1   [84.241.34.239:61310]   'upd.es-eset.com.'
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I can sort with `jq`. It also sorts the domain names too.

Comment: @Saeed The sorting of the domain names happens with the grouping (as we group by the domain names, and the implementation of `group_by` automatically (and infact unnecessarily) sorts the array first, rendering it quite inefficient). Instead, one could implement a `reduce`-based solution which can not only keep the original order but can also save you from reading the entire file into memory, which might be relevant with large input files. Let me know if you want me to add an example for that as well.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I solve the problem:

```
awk '/DNSHandler:ProxyResolver\] Request|Reply/ {print $5, $8}' file.log | sort -k2 | uniq -c -f1 | sort -k1r
```

Output:

```
      6 [86.104.44.22:62248] 'th.bing.com.'
      5 [86.104.44.22:62836] 'www.bing.com.'
      4 [86.104.44.22:62719] 'a1834.dscg2.akamai.NET.'
      2 [94.182.110.194:51644] 'raja-bot.utravs.com.'
      2 [86.104.44.22:63587] 'hlb.apr-52dd2-0.edgecastdns.NET.'
      2 [86.104.44.22:62881] 'wns.notify.trafficmanager.NET.'
      2 [86.104.44.22:62452] 'onedscolprdwus08.westus.cloudapp.azure.com.'
      2 [84.241.34.239:56795] 'dns.msftncsi.com.'
      2 [84.241.34.239:53210] 'yunqos.gamesafe.qq.com.'
      2 [84.241.34.239:49270] 'update.eset.com.'
      1 [84.241.34.239:61310] 'upd.es-eset.com.'
```

Answer (score 3):

Assumptions/Understandings:

- accumulate counts based on a combination of the ip + domain
- a unique ip + domain pair may have multiple ports; we just need to display one of the ports; which port we display is unimportant [?? if this is the case then why display any ports ??]

Pulling everything but a `sort` call into `awk`:

```
awk '
BEGIN { regex = "DNSHandler:ProxyResolver]$" }

$3 ~ regex && \
$4 ~ /Reply:|Request:/ { split($5,a,"[:[]")         # a[2] == ip address
                         counts[a[2]][$8]++         # counts[ip][domain]
                         ports[a[2]]= $5            # store latest port; will overwrite previous port
                       }
END                    { for (ip in counts)
                             for (domain in counts[ip])
                                 print counts[ip][domain],ports[ip],domain
                       }
' file.log | sort -k1r
```

**NOTES:**

- requires `GNU awk` for multidimesional arrays (aka array of arrays)
- with `GNU awk` the sorting can be performed within the `awk` script (ie, the `sort -k1r` call could be eliminated) but in this case the `sort -k1r` is a bit more straightforward
- I've copied `sort -k1r` from OP's answer; I'm assuming OP has confirmed this is sufficient to generate the desired result

This generates:

```
6 [86.104.44.22:62881] 'th.bing.com.'
5 [86.104.44.22:62881] 'www.bing.com.'
4 [86.104.44.22:62881] 'a1834.dscg2.akamai.NET.'
2 [94.182.110.194:51644] 'raja-bot.utravs.com.'
2 [86.104.44.22:62881] 'wns.notify.trafficmanager.NET.'
2 [86.104.44.22:62881] 'onedscolprdwus08.westus.cloudapp.azure.com.'
2 [86.104.44.22:62881] 'hlb.apr-52dd2-0.edgecastdns.NET.'
2 [84.241.34.239:61310] 'yunqos.gamesafe.qq.com.'
2 [84.241.34.239:61310] 'update.eset.com.'
2 [84.241.34.239:61310] 'dns.msftncsi.com.'
1 [84.241.34.239:61310] 'upd.es-eset.com.'
```

Comment: `if this is the case then why display any ports`: because that's the output of a DNS server which shows for example a request was sent to resolve `bing.com`, another for another domain. It's not controlled by me. The IP here doesn't matter really, but I need to see some specific domains to test if it's working properly.

Comment: sure, I understand the port is included in the log file;  my question is referring to the output from this set of code; we're spliting the ip and port so there's no reason why we couldn't display *just* the ip (and not display any port)

Comment: Aha, got it. Yes, there's no need to show the IP. You can omit and ignore that.